# Scroll arduino LCD 20x4

Tags: scroll, arduino, lcd

Good Morning. I have an LCD20x4 display and I need to move two lines simultaneously. I tried as follows:

```
    scrollText(0, name, 250, lcdColumns);
    scrollText(2, mother, 250, lcdColumns);




void scrollText(int row, String message, int delayTime, int lcdColumns) {
  for (int i=0; i < lcdColumns; i++) {
    message = " " + message; 
  } 
  message = message + " "; 
  for (int pos = 0; pos < message.length(); pos++) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, row);
    lcd.print(message.substring(pos, pos + lcdColumns));
    delay(delayTime);
  }
}
```

However, the second line does not begin to move until the first one comes to an end. How to solve this problem?

Comment: why do you expect your code to scroll two lines at the same time if you explicitly call your `scrollText` function for each line with a 250ms delay?

Comment: Can I call both lines with the same function?

The 250ms is the time the text is displayed on the screen

Comment: well your code scrolls one line and then the other line. I'm not sure why you say you tried to scroll two lines at the same time with this approach. have you tried to do both lnes in the same loop? is there anything else on your display? or just those two lines?